# Why is Dany unable to control her dragon?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

History goes that Aegon and his dragon conquered the seven kingdoms, which implies that Aegon had good command over his dragon.
Jorah said something about the dragon to Dany that dragons can not be fully tamed. Did other Targeryens also have so loose control over their dragons or is it only Dany? The show doesn't give much explanation, does the book says anything over why Dany seems to be unable to control her dragon(s)?

Comment: No dragon horn. :)

Comment: @TLP You think Euron is correct about the Horn's powers? Aemond Targaryen displayed taking over Vhagar, without any horn. (I think Aemond's the only character which demonstrates taking a new dragon other than Dragonseeds)

Comment: @Aegon It would be Moqorro The Black Flame whose word I would choose to take, from when he read the runes on the horn to Victarion.

Comment: @TLP Moqorro may or may not be correct seeing as Red Priests have erred many times before. In any case, it should be interesting seeing as WoW Aerion chapter has almost confirmed Euron indeed went to Valyria so the horn maybe real. But in current state, Everytime we see a person with dragonblood, no horn was ever present.

Comment: @Aegon Interesting, I had not read that chapter. The AERON chapter, I assume you mean. Well, if Euron thought the horn worked, he would have used it himself no doubt. It may not be the only way to control a dragon.

Comment: @TLP Yes Aeron, sorry for the typo. Well when you read it, I am sure you would really hate Euron (I know I do now). The horn has some magical properties for sure given how it burns people who sound it. And since Valyrians used magic to bind dragons and their magic is based on fire and blood, It may as well be able to bind dragons using blood and internal combustion of the blower.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Aegon had the luxury of having a whole clan of dragon riders around him. They had the knowledge and the expertise to tame and train a dragon. The novella "The Princess and the Queen", which chronicles the first Targaryen civil war (known as the Dance of the Dragons), had a more detailed look at the process of training a dragon (and rider) for war. It was a difficult and highly dangerous process even with all the facilities and expertise.

On the other hand you have Danaerys, who was born into a world that hadn't even *seen* dragons for almost 150 years. Not only that, she didn't have anyone around her who knew anything about dragons nor had she even access to books on the subject. It even took her a while to learn how to feed her baby dragons properly. In essence, she's flying blind.

Comment: Much more fleshed out answer than mine. +1

Comment: She's doing better with the dragons than anyone else has. Where dragons are concerned, not being burned to a crisp and eaten is an achievement.

Answer (score 9):

The Targaryens who conquered Westeros were used to having dragons and training them. Dany just happened to hatch three dragons and she has to learn everything by herself.

Answer (score 3):

Despite being born at Dragonstone in Westeros, *Aegon the Conqueror*'s house came from Valyria along with their dragons. Valyria at that time was a hot place for magic, spells and dragon-riders. The dragon lords used magic to control dragons among other things. It is speculated that over-use of magic may have been the main cause for the *doom of Valyria*.

*Daenerys* however doesn't know the old Valyrian magic, nor have a way to acquire such information. Also, she sees the dragons as her children; she is hesitant to use such measures. This may change this over time.

In "A Dance With Dragons", *Euron Greyjoy* claims to possess a *horn* from the Valyrian Wastelands that controls the dragons. We can only wait for the book/show to elaborate more such relics.

Comment: This is a good answer, but your first sentence is actually wrong. http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_I_Targaryen Aegon was born on Dragonstone, which the Targaryens had already held for over a century, around the time of the Doom.

Comment: oh that does makes it. It was Aenar who came to westeros. thank you for pointing

Comment: you can [edit] your answer then :)